# Configurable products for different product sizes and price

Tags: configurable-product, price, customer-group

I am trying to make a store for car care chemicals in Magento for online buyers and company distributors.

Each chemical has a size option - 0.5 liters, 5 liters, 207 liters

And the above options have price difference depending upon the customer is a normal buyer or a distributor.

I have made a configurable product, but the price in the "Super product attributes configuration" overrides the Group pricing in the simple products.

Can somebody please suggest the right way?

Comment: I think you need to set visibility to "catalog/search" for child product while "not visible individually" for parent product (config product) in you case.

Answer (score 2):

By default, it is not possible to use the price attributes of the associated products. You have to set up group pricing in the configurable product itself.